# Firebase Storage Security Rules

Tags: firebase, security, google-cloud-platform, firebase-storage, firebase-security

I am using fire base storage for my application which connects to front end.
My current storage rules for only of the bucket folders is :

```
match {groupID}/{userId}/{image} {
        allow read: if isValidProvider() && request.auth.token.groupId == groupID && request.auth.uid == userId;
        allow write: if isValidProvider() && request.auth.uid == userId &&  request.auth.token.groupId== groupID && isImageValid() && isValidImageExtension(image);
      }
    }
```

Functions are as below :

```
function isImageValid(){
    return (request.resource.contentType.matches('image/png') ||
        request.resource.contentType.matches('image/jpg') ||
        request.resource.contentType.matches('image/jpeg') ||
        request.resource.contentType.matches('image/webp') ||
          request.resource.contentType.matches('image/gif'));
        
  }



  function isValidImageExtension(image) {
  return (image.matches('.*[.]png') || 
      image.matches('.*[.]jpeg') ||
      image.matches('.*[.]jpg') ||
      image.matches('.*[.]webp')||
      image.matches('.*[.]gif'));
  }
```

My intention is the read access is given on groupID basis and write access is given on user ID basis.
Also, in the folder - it should only accept images with formats - png/jpeg/jpg/webp/gif

However, while trying to test this via postman - I am able to add a ndjson file or .py file.
For Example - The API call ends with - test.jpg but in the body - binary I am adding a .py file.
Also, in the storage the .py is saved as type - image/jpg.

This is being added to the storage.

How can I restrict only image files be added from backend ?

Comment: Best way to achieve this would be a backend side file type validation before you put the file in the firebase storage. Why do you want firebase rules to handle this?

Comment: we have been planning to use backend side file validation - but wanted to understand if the same can be achieved via rules. That would be a quick fix. 
Otherwise, backend validation would be a lot of architecture change.

Comment: Can you edit your question to show how you upload the file?

Comment: Hi @FrankvanPuffelen 

My API Call is something like - https://$API_URL2%2Ftest.jpg

And then in body - I go to binary and add .py file. 
It gives me success response 200 OK. 
Also, the same py file is added in my bucket. 
Which I ideally expect to be blocked by rules. Because of the contentType Validation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation on [uploading files](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/upload-files#add_file_metadata) is clearest on how `contentType` is determined:

> The `putFile()` method automatically infers the MIME type from the File extension, but you can override the auto-detected type by specifying `contentType` in the metadata. If you do not provide a `contentType` and Cloud Storage cannot infer a default from the file extension, Cloud Storage uses `application/octet-stream`.

So Firebase does **not** look at the actual contents of the file to set determine the content type.

Instead the content type is derived from the filename extension, and you can override that by explicitly setting the content type in the metadata when you upload the file.

Since you don't set metadata, the content type is determined from the `.jpg` extension in the file name. The Python contents are not used in determining that.

---

If you want a stricter check on content type, consider running a Cloud Function that is triggered on an upload and use a file type sniffer that looks at the actual contents of the file to validate the type. You could then either remove the file if its contents don't match its type, or for example add a `verified` property to the metadata that you can then check in clients.

Comment: Can you please suggest any example of file type sniffer ?
Is it like clamAV or something else?

Comment: Suggesting off-site libraries is off-topic, which is why I didn't include any. But a search should give you reasonable options: https://www.google.com/search?q=node.js+type+sniffer

Comment: Hi @Frankvanpuffelen - Thanks for your help. I couldn't check this earlier.

Answer (score -1):

I have found a way to validate [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security#section-validation). Does this help you?

Comment: This is for realtime database - we are working for firebase storage.

Comment: I have found this also. https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/security#data_validation